# Not able to read connection string from app config

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, server

This is my connection string in App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CostAllocationEntities2" connectionString="Data Source=PC210090\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;
         User ID=sa;password=password-1;multipleactiveresultsets=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>

     ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CostAllocationEntities2"].ConnectionString);

                    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

                    Database db = sqlServer.Databases[strDBName];
```

> Exception : Failed to connect to server Data Source=PC210090\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;
>                User ID=sa;password=password-1;multipleactiveresultsets=True; .

Comment: Have you checked whether you are able to connect to the database via Management Studio using same credentials?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do, not sure but change your connection string

`connectionString="Data Source=PC210090\\SQLEXPRESS;`

`Initial Catalog=master;`; don't connect to `master` DB rather provide a user DB name like `Sample`.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CostAllocationEntities2" connectionString="Data Source=PC210090\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Sample;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=test;password=test;multipleactiveresultsets=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In your code behind

Once you have the connection string create a instance of SqlConnection like

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CostAllocationEntities2"].ConnectionString);
```

Open the connection

```
connection.Open();
```